# How to delete fonts in ubuntu

Tags: fonts

How to delete fonts in ubuntu. I am a new ubuntu user and find it hard to delete fonts that I have installed.

I anticipate that the problem might be installing font that turns my Firefox browser turned my mail fonts to bold. I experience the same view with firefox and chrome browser. Many of the fonts turned out to be bold.!

Comment: Follow the steps: 1. Go to your home folder 2. Press Ctrl+H or (Menu -> View -> Show Hidden Files) 3. Go to .fonts 4. Delete all Roboto bold fonts 5. Restart your browser 6. How are your eyes feeling now! Done.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I remove fonts that I never use, from libreoffice and linux in general?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214950/how-can-i-remove-fonts-that-i-never-use-from-libreoffice-and-linux-in-general)

Answer (score 41):

An easy way to do that is using font manager.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+
<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

Once installed, run the program, highlight the fonts that you don't like, and either disable or remove them.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Good choice! But, by default it search for custom fonts only in ~/.fonts, instead in "Preferences" I added also ~/.local/share/fonts, because it's the folder used by install feature of Font Viewer.

Comment: The current version of Font Manager has a different UI and appears to make it [impossible to delete fonts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/font-manager/+bug/1810907).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Which version of font manager are you referring to?

Comment: As is says in the bug I linked to, 0.7.3-1.1

Comment: @DanDascalescu you may not be able to delete, but I was able to disable a font, and opened LibreOffice writer, and the font was not listed.

Comment: Hello, when I click the minus button, a popup appears saying: "Fonts installed in your home directory will appear here" 
I have file manager 0.7.7

Comment: @DanDascalescu Is correct. This is no longer a useful answer.

Answer (score 25):

**First**, determine the font's name you want to delete, example 'Nimbus Sans L'

Then run the following command in terminal to know where it is:

```
$ fc-list "Nimbus Sans L"
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019063l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019064l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019043l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019044l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019023l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019024l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019004l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019003l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular
```

In case you don't know the exact font name, just try `fc-match -s Nimbus` 
or `fc-list |grep -i nimbus`, those commands will give you a hint.

**Second**, delete what you wanna. Below, for example, should delete style `Bold Condensed Italic` of 'Nimbus Sans L':

```
$ sudo rm /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019064l.pfb
```

After deleting, type this command to update the font cache database:

```
$ fc-cache -fv
```

If if doesn't effect, you need to reboot the system by:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hello @mja Can you tell me how to install "Nimbus Sans L" in Ubuntu 18.04 using cmd.

Comment: `sudo apt install gsfonts`

Answer (score 17):

You can also delete them manually.

(That can be useful in some cases, for example: if you want to use a program like `conky` with a thin font like Raleway Thin, but Raleway Regular was also installed, `conky` may sometime automatically use regular, while `font-manager` will not be able to tell the difference. So, the idea is to remove regular manually, etc.)

If installed with Font Viewer, they are in `~/.local/share/fonts`.

Also look in `~/.fonts`.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 18

Launch a file manager as sugo (e.g. `sudo nautilus`) and navigate to `/usr/share/fonts`. Browse through the `opentype` and especially the `truetype` directory, and delete fonts you don't want. (If you really dislike the fonts, press Shift+Delete for extra effect :)

[image: Junk fonts]

After deleting, run this command to update the font cache:

```
$ fc-cache -fv
```

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the fonts with `apt` then you can

```
sudo apt remove fonts-<fontname>
```

You can see a list of all the fonts you installed with `apt` using

```
apt list --installed | grep ^fonts
```

or to see all fonts available from `apt` do

```
apt search ^fonts-
```