# Removal of fonts

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, fonts

**How do I remove fonts I don't want?** (preferred using GUI)

---

I tried the following without success:

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the Font Manager looks nothing like the one shown here.

Selecting one or more fonts and hitting the '-' button does not remove the font(s) but just shows a blank window.

I tried the manual method 4 (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214950/how-can-i-remove-fonts-that-i-never-use-from-libreoffice-and-linux-in-general)). above and found the font locations.

I managed to remove the 'noto' font folder but that font family still appears in applications such as LibreOffice 5, even after a system restart.

I cannot use the terminal command line method, as I don't know what the font names are that should be used. They would appear to differ from what's in the application drop-down lists.

Having spent several hours on this with absolutely no success, I've come to the conclusion that there really should be some foolproof gui method for users to select fonts from a list and delete them.

How do I remove fonts I don't want? (preferred using GUI)

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214950/how-can-i-remove-fonts-that-i-never-use-from-libreoffice-and-linux-in-general/878501#878501) is the best answer I've found for this question. Instead of removing fonts you don't want, you keep only the ones you do. It's command-line based, but the other answers to the question I linked, do present GUI solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not GUI, but very effective. Use `fc-list` tool in terminal to get list of font files. Just delete files you don't need.

If you want to filter some fonts use

```
fc-list | grep -i Noto
```

Where `Noto` is a part of font name, `-i` is a key to ignore case while search.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out `gnome-tweak-tool` or `unity-tweak-tool` based on what desktop manager you are using. You can install these by `sudo apt-get install` followed by one of the aforementioned packages.
You can also try the application called `lxappearance`.

These applications will let you choose system wide fonts. I do not understand why do you need to delete and have never done that changing system fonts is pretty easy using these.

Further, if you want to use some new fonts which are not their in the system by default then, make a folder `~/.fonts`.

`mkdir ~/.fonts`

Now add the `*.ttf` files for any font which you download and then just choose that font form the menu in any of these applications.