# Is there a simple way for uninstalling fonts?

Tags: fonts

How can I uninstall a font on Ubuntu 17.04?  I've just installed a font and it's not functioning correctly (Arabic font).  I need to get rid of it so it doesn't cause any troubles or errors every time I open Libreoffice. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the .ttf file and clicked install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove fonts that I never use, from libreoffice and linux in general?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214950/how-can-i-remove-fonts-that-i-never-use-from-libreoffice-and-linux-in-general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in 'Software-Center' for `font-manager` (font management application for the GNOME desktop) and install it, with it you should be able to easily find and delete the font.

[image: Install via the software center]

---

Alternatively you can install it in Terminal by:

```
sudo apt install font-manager
```

---

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful.  I have a font manager now :-))  Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: @NermeenHussein: can font manager [actually remove fonts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/font-manager/+bug/1810907)?